# Using a switch statement to append URL structure

Tags: php

So I have the following switch statement inside a method inside my class:

```
public function getSASURL(string $blobName, string $size = '') : string
{
    if ($this->containerName === 'userpictures-resized') {
        switch ($size) {
            case 'small':
                return '_SThumb';
                break;
            case 'medium':
                return '_MThumb';
                break;
            case 'large':
                return '_LThumb';
                break;
            case 'original':
                return '_Original';
                break;
            case 'big':
                return '_Big';
                break;
        }
        return $this->generateSASURL($blobName . $size . '.jpg');
    }
    return $this->generateSASURL($blobName);
}
```

**Here is what it's doing**:

When I call:

```
$sasURL = $azure->getSASURL('AHahn_com');
```

I get the following thing back - this works as expected.

```
https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/userpictures-resized/AHahn_com.jpg?sv=2017-11-09&sr=b&st=2020-10-08T13:04:47Z
```

Now when I call:

```
$sasURL = $azure->getSASURL('AHahn_com', 'small');
```

I get the following back:

```
'_SThumb'
```

Instead, this is the result that I want to receive back (with `_SThumb` after the filename, before the extension):

```
https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/userpictures-resized/AHahn_com_SThumb.jpg?sv=2017-11-09&sr=b&st=2020-10-08T13:04:47Z
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: We cant help you without knowing how `$this->containerName` is defined/used.

Comment: You `return` from the function within your switch statement, whereas you should modify `$blobName`.

Comment: You `return` within your `switch` statement, so there's nothing unexpected about that. You should alter to your `$size` variable instead, like `$size = '_SThumb';` instead of `return '_SThumb';`

Comment: Each `case` just `return`s a short string. It's not going through the `$this->generateSASURL(...)`…

Comment: Should I bypass the case returns or do I have to define generateSASURL in each return under cases?

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful @Qirel, this worked!

Comment: @Qirel If you'd like to upvote my answer and post a answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you `return` from the `switch` statement rather than use the value for each case. You can either overwrite `$size` inside each case, so for example `$size = '_SThumb';` instead of `return '_SThumb';`, or create another variable which you substitute for `$size` to your `generateSASURL()` method.

However, another approach could be to create a map of the sizes and their corresponding value. Then just access the array with `$size` as a key. To make it case-insensitve, you can do `$map[strtolower($size)]`. The default value (when no match was found) is the value after the null-coalescing operator `??`, which could be anything - here it's `$size`, but it could be an empty string if that's more applicable.

```php
public function getSASURL(string $blobName, string $size = '') : string
{
    if ($this->containerName === 'userpictures-resized') {
        $map = [
            'size' => '_SThumb',
            'medium' => '_SThumb',
            'large' => '_MThumb',
            'original' => '_Original',
            'big' => '_Big',
        ];
        return $this->generateSASURL($blobName . ($map[$size] ?? $size) . '.jpg');
    }
    return $this->generateSASURL($blobName);
}
```